# cmake replace string in custom target

Tags: cmake

I want to have a cmake target that updates a specific file.
I tried following but it seems that I cannot put all what I want into a custom target.

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(update
            file(READ "file.h" myFile)
            string(REPLACE "originalString" "newString" myFile"${myFile}"))
            )
```

I'm quite new to cmake so I may be missing something basic. How could I update the file on request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I personally use for this type of problem is use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html). Essentially, you can make what you consider a template file and wrap variable names in the files.

```
Example.h.template
Here is my @VAR@
```

Then if you have VAR defined in your CMake project, it will replace VAR in your destination.

```
configure_file(<input> <output> NEWLINE_STYLE WIN32)
```

If input (your template) is modified, CMake will be re-run to keep your file up to date. So in your cmake you can

```
set(VAR "program")
configure_file("Path/To/Example.h.template" "Path/To/File.h" NEWLINE_STYLE [UNIX|DOS|WIN32|LF|CRLF])
```

The result should be:

```
File.h
Here is my program
```